# NameError: name 'convertToBinaryData' is not defined

Tags: python, mysql, sql, file

I'm having trouble figuring out why I am getting the error: NameError: name 'convertToBinaryData' is not defined, any ideas?

I think the declaration of the function convertToBinaryData is in the right place, although I'm not sure how to fix this issue

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\USER............\TestDB.py", line 20, in 
> db.insertRawEcg(1, 2, "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\...\...\...\ecgexample.jpg", True, True, 0.08, 0.08, True, 0.04, 0.2, 0.04, 0.2,
> File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop.........\DBConnect.py", line 146, in insertRawEcg
> scanPic = convertToBinaryData(EcgScan)
> NameError: name 'convertToBinaryData' is not defined
> [Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]

**DBConnect.py**

```
import mysql.connector
import datetime
import sys

class DBConnect:
        config = {
          'user': 'root',
          'password': 'root',
          'host': 'localhost',
          'database': 'EcgDB',
          'raise_on_warnings': True,
        }

        examOccurence = datetime.datetime.now()
        currDate = examOccurence.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
        currTime = examOccurence.strftime("%H:%M:%S")


        link = mysql.connector.connect(**config) #Establishing connection
        mycourser = link.cursor(buffered=True) #Creating cursor object to allow execution of SQL statements

        
        MeasurementsTable = """CREATE TABLE MeasurementsOfPatient(
                                            ExamID int,
                                            EcgID int,
                                            ExamDate date,
                                            ExamTime time,
                                            PRIMARY KEY (ExamID, EcgID)

                                )"""

        PatientsTable = """CREATE TABLE patients (
                                        PatientID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                        GroupID int,
                                        ExamID int,
                                        Age int,
                                        Gender char(1) NOT NULL,
                                        MedBackground VARCHAR(255),
                                        PRIMARY KEY (PatientID),
                                        FOREIGN KEY (ExamID) 
                                            REFERENCES MeasurementsOfPatient(ExamID)
                                            ON UPDATE CASCADE,
                                        FOREIGN KEY (GroupID)
                                            REFERENCES users(GroupID)
                                            ON UPDATE CASCADE
                                            
                            )"""

        UsersTable = """CREATE TABLE users (
                                    UserName VARCHAR(255),
                                    PassWord VARCHAR(255),
                                    GroupID int,
                                    PRIMARY KEY (UserName, PassWord),
                                    UNIQUE (GroupID)

                    )"""

        EcgRawDataTable = """CREATE TABLE EcgRawData (
                                            ExamID int,
                                            EcgID int,
                                            EcgScan MEDIUMBLOB,
                                            Lead boolean,
                                            Pwave boolean,
                                            PXlength DECIMAL(3, 2),
                                            PwaveAvg DECIMAL(3, 2),
                                            Qwave boolean,
                                            QXlength DECIMAL(3, 2),
                                            QYlength DECIMAL(3, 2),
                                            QwaveAvgX DECIMAL(3, 2),
                                            QwaveAvgY DECIMAL(3, 2),
                                            Swave boolean,
                                            SXlength DECIMAL(3, 2),
                                            SYlength DECIMAL(3, 2),
                                            SwaveAvgX DECIMAL(3, 2),
                                            SwaveAvgY DECIMAL(3, 2),
                                            Twave boolean,
                                            Rwave boolean,
                                            RwaveAvg DECIMAL(3, 2),
                                            PRinterval DECIMAL(3, 2),
                                            QRSinterval DECIMAL(3, 2),
                                            RRinterval DECIMAL(3, 2),
                                            HeartRate int,
                                            RespiratoryRate int,
                                            HeartRythem VARCHAR(255),
                                            FOREIGN KEY (ExamID, EcgID) 
                                                REFERENCES MeasurementsOfPatient(ExamID, EcgID)
                                                ON UPDATE CASCADE

                    )"""

        EcgParamsTable = """CREATE TABLE EcgParams(
                                        ExamID int,
                                        EcgID int,
                                        EcgScan MEDIUMBLOB,
                                        Lead boolean,
                                        Pwave boolean,
                                        PXlength DECIMAL(3, 2),
                                        PwaveAvg DECIMAL(3, 2),
                                        Qwave boolean,
                                        QXlength DECIMAL(3, 2),
                                        QYlength DECIMAL(3, 2),
                                        QwaveAvgX DECIMAL(3, 2),
                                        QwaveAvgY DECIMAL(3, 2),
                                        Swave boolean,
                                        SXlength DECIMAL(3, 2),
                                        SYlength DECIMAL(3, 2),
                                        SwaveAvgX DECIMAL(3, 2),
                                        SwaveAvgY DECIMAL(3, 2),
                                        Twave boolean,
                                        Rwave boolean,
                                        RwaveAvg DECIMAL(3, 2),
                                        PRinterval DECIMAL(3, 2),
                                        QRSinterval DECIMAL(3, 2),
                                        RRinterval DECIMAL(3, 2),
                                        HeartRate int,
                                        RespiratoryRate int,
                                        HeartRythem VARCHAR(255),
                                        FOREIGN KEY (ExamID, EcgID) 
                                            REFERENCES MeasurementsOfPatient(ExamID, EcgID)
                                            ON UPDATE CASCADE
                                                    

                    )"""


    def convertToBinaryData(self, filename):
        #Convert digital data to binary format
        with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
            binaryData = file.read()
        return binaryData

    def write_file(self, data, filename):
        #convert binary data to proper format and write it on hard disk
        with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(data)

    def insertRawEcg(self, ExamID, EcgID, EcgScan, Lead, Pwave, PXlength, PwaveAvg, 
                      Qwave, QXlength, QYlength, QwaveAvgX, QwaveAvgY, Swave,
                      SXlength, SYlength, SwaveAvgX, SwaveAvgY, Twave, Rwave,
                      RwaveAvg, PRinterval, QRSinterval, RRinterval, HeartRate,
                      RespiratoryRate, HeartRythem):
        
        insertScan = """INSERT INTO EcgRawData VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""

        scanPic = convertToBinaryData(EcgScan)

        dataTuple = (ExamID, EcgID, scanPic, Lead, Pwave, PXlength, PwaveAvg, 
                      Qwave, QXlength, QYlength, QwaveAvgX, QwaveAvgY, Swave,
                      SXlength, SYlength, SwaveAvgX, SwaveAvgY, Twave, Rwave,
                      RwaveAvg, PRinterval, QRSinterval, RRinterval, HeartRate,
                      RespiratoryRate, HeartRythem)

        cursor.execute(insertScan, dataTuple)
        link.commit()
        print("Raw data inserted successfully to DB")
```

**TestDB.py**

```
from DBConnect import DBConnect

db = DBConnect()

db.insertRawEcg(1, 2, "C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\...\\...\\...\\ecgexample.jpg", True, True, 0.08, 0.08, True, 0.04, 0.2, 0.04, 0.2, True, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, True, True,0.08, 1, 2, 4, 60, 13, "NSR")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `scanPic = self.convertToBinaryData(EcgScan)` since `convertToBinaryData` is a class method.

Comment: Thanks but now I'm getting -  NameError: name 'mycursor' is not defined

Comment: Where is it used? In the following line of code there is a spelling mistake.      `mycourser = link.cursor(buffered=True) #Creating cursor object to allow execution of SQL statements`